# How to layout images in a grid?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have 3 rows of images. Each image is made up of:

```
<span class="tribeimg">
<img src="images/tribes/img.jpg">
<p class="lt-tribe-name">Tribe Name</p>
</span>
```

with CSS..

```
.tribeimg {
background-color: black;
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
width: 140px;
height: 140px;
}

.tribeimg img {
opacity: 0.7;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 0;
}

.tribeimg img:hover, .tribeimg p:hover {
cursor: pointer;
}

.tribeimg .lt-tribe-name {
opacity: 0.7;
z-index: 11;
color: white;
position: absolute;
left: 32px;
bottom: 50px;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 8px black;
}
```

You can see the layout here: `http://128.199.58.229/landingpage/`

The images were aligning correctly until I tried to add text on the image. That broke the layout.

How do I fix it? Or is there a better way to lay them out? In the second row I have the exception of a div block with no image.. so it's not a straight forward image grid exactly.

Thanks.

Comment: What text you added? How does the alignment change?

Comment: Not sure I've fully understood what you're after, but `.lt-block-tagline { vertical-align: top }` seems to get things in line again at least.

Comment: Sorry, It's unclear what you're asking here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `vertical-align: top` to `.lt-block-tagline`.

```
.lt-block-tagline {
    background-color: #0590A0;
    width: 420px;
    height: 140px;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 30px;
    padding: 18px;
    font-family: "Lato";
    line-height: 32px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

[image]

---

To remove the spacing between the rows add `height: 140px` to `.lt-tribe-img-row`.

```
.lt-tribe-img-row {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 140px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes this works thanks :) How to remove the extra spacing between rows?

Comment: Got it. Thanks. Updated the answer so the CSS is applied to .lt-tribe-img-row

Answer (score 0):

Try remove position: absolute from .tribeimg img

```
.tribeimg img {
   position: static;
}
```

Comment: doesn't help at all...